# Change foreColor and BackColor of DataGridViewRows in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to change the rows forecolor and backcolor in my Dtgrdview, where Column of iRemaining != 0,
by this code:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow DG in dtgrdUCBuyInvoices.Rows)
            if((Int64)DG.Cells["iRemaining"].Value != 0)
            {
                DG.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                DG.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            }
```

but it doesn't work and Colors don't Change !!!

how can i fix it?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: "But it doesn't work" is not very helpful... What doesn't work? Colors do not change? Do you get a error?

Comment: excuse me , Colors do not change, without error

Comment: Have you traced this with the debugger? I would check to see what `Value` is returning.

Comment: yes, the commands of the If works when iRemaining returns a value !=0 , but Colors don't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to change the row color outside of the `DataGridView` rendering.

Let's try to add your code to the `RowPrePaint` event of your `DataGridView`:

```
private void dtgrdUCBuyInvoices_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
  if ((Int64)dtgrdUCBuyInvoices.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["iRemaining"].Value != 0)
    {
      dtgrdUCBuyInvoices.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
      dtgrdUCBuyInvoices.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

And register it during initialization:

```
dtgrdUCBuyInvoices.RowPrePaint += new DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventHandler(dtgrdUCBuyInvoices_RowPrePaint);
```

Comment: thanks , but other DataGridViews works by this code outside of the DataGridView rendering, then why doesn't it work for this DataGridView ?

Comment: Do you change row color of other DataGridViews in the same function ? It's hard to tell just with the code you provided.

Comment: Can you give more contextual information, where in your code were you trying to refresh this DataGridView  and where are you refreshing the other DataGridViews for exemple ?

Comment: right after this :     SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("BuyInvoicesShow", SCon);    SDA.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;    SDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeId", 0);    DataTable DT = new DataTable();    SDA.Fill(DT);  DT.Columns.Add("RR");    for (int i = 0; i < DT.Rows.Count; i++)    {DT.Rows[i]["RR"] = i + 1;}    dtgrdUCBuyInvoices.DataSource = DT;    foreach (DataGridViewRow ..)

Comment: That is not was I meant, can you tell what are the differences between the way you handle this DataGridView and the others that were working well ?

Answer (score 1):

I am just guessing here possibly, but how you are getting and comparing the values is most likely failing. Also in your posted code, if the cells value is not 0, then you want to set the whole row red? Below is code that converts the string value of the cell and if it’s not zero (0) it sets that cells back color and fore color. Try the code below and see if it helps.

```
Int64 cellValue = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow DG in dtgrdUCBuyInvoices.Rows) {
  if (!DG.IsNewRow && DG.Cells["iRemaining"].Value != null) {
    Int64.TryParse(DG.Cells["iRemaining"].Value.ToString(), out cellValue);
    if (cellValue != 0) {
      DG.Cells["iRemaining"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
      DG.Cells["iRemaining"].Style.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works only for iRemaining Column when i put inside of the DataGridView rendering, but other DataGridViews works by my code outside of the DataGridView rendering, then why doesn't it work for this DataGridView ?

Comment: The line `(Int64)dgvr.Cells["iRemaining"].Value` should be throwing an error. A `DataGridView` does not have a cell type of Int64. Try this line of code it will crash `Int64 cellValue = (Int64)dgvr.Cells["iRemaining"].Value;`